# Require Rails lib file that has the same name as a core Ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Outside of rails, I have the following:

```
|- file1.rb
|- matrix.rb
```

With the following content:

```
# in matrix.rb
class Matrix
  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end
end

# in file1.rb
require_relative 'matrix'
require 'matrix'

Matrix.build(1,1) { 0 }.foo
```

Running `ruby file1.rb` outputs:

> foo

I was able to include and call both my matrix file and the core matrix class.

In Rails, I have the following directory structure:

```
|- lib
|-- core_ext
|--- matrix.rb
|- test
|-- lib
|--- core_ext
|---- matrix_test.rb
```

And the contents:

```
# in test/lib/core_ext/matrix_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
require_relative "#{Dir.pwd}/lib/core_ext/matrix.rb"
require 'matrix'

class MatrixTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'matrix foo' do
    Matrix.new.foo
    Matrix.build(1,1) { 0 }.foo
    assert true
  end
end
```

When I run `rake test test/lib/core_ext/matrix_test.rb`, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'build' for Matrix:Class` , which mean the core 'matrix' file hasn't been loaded.

I worked around this by renaming my lib file but I do wish to include both of Ruby's core Matrix and mine without renaming the files. Any suggestions?

p.s: I'm using ruby 2.1.4p265 and Rails 4.1.6

Comment: Try Adding require 'matrix.rb'

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Hemali. Still, the same. I think require thinks that 'matrix' has already been loaded because it has the same name as my lib/matrix.

Comment: Ideally, I would go for a namespaced solution. Like `myproject/matrix` to avoid nameclashes like this. Unless you are deliberately extending a core class. If you are deliberately extending a core class, I generally do that in an initializer (in rails).

Comment: You should change your custom class name to something else rather `Matrix`.

Comment: I am actually patching the core class =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think this has to do with Rails' autoload which overrides `const_missing` and messes up the way files are natively required in Ruby. http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/

The thing is, regardless of the order of my requires in Ruby, both my 'matrix' and the core matrix ARE being loaded and the code was behaving as expected.

When Rails runs and attempts to auto load `lib/core_ext/matrix.rb`, it's expecting it to define `CoreExt::Matrix`. When I was doing `require 'matrix'` in the code, this was returning false: the core matrix library wasn't being loaded because rails assumes it has been loaded? (I'm not sure about this but this is where this might be happening: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb )

What I had to do was rename my `matrix.rb` to `matrix_ext.rb` even though the class defined in `matrix_ext.rb` was `Matrix`. This is the workaround I had mentioned in my question but I didn't know why this was happening.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrap `Matrix` class in module then `refine ... do; end` and `def` methods:

```
# lib/core_ext/my_ext_matrix.rb
module MyExtMatrix
  refine Matrix do
    def foo
      puts 'foo'
    end
  end
end
```

Now `using` you ext:

```
# .... some code here ....

class MatrixTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  using MyExtMatrix

  test 'matrix foo' do
    Matrix.new.foo
    Matrix.build(1,1) { 0 }.foo
    assert true
  end
end
```

After `using`  you should be able use methods from core `Matrix` and own `refine`ed.

Comment: Awesome! This makes perfect sense!

Comment: Actually, I thought this was what I'm looking for. It's a great answer with refinements. I would like my monkey-patching to be global though. I don't want to be "using" my "MyExtMatrix" every time.

Comment: @Abdo my pleasure, i think `refine` very powerful feature in right place.

Comment: you can add `using` method on runtime, where you need, or just using ext module when `Rails` start `send(:using, MyExtMatrix)` somewhere :)

Comment: Good idea :-) The thing though is that I want to reuse this code in many places simply by adding it to lib and having lib in autoload. The functionality would become available everywhere regardless if I forget to add `send(:using, MyExtMatrix)`. I don't want to forget this. Also, if we're doing this globally, why are we using `refine` instead of simply monkey patching?

Comment: i can't see full picture of a app, what should be right in your case you better know, just show some other `in-built` way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64171/discussion-between-abdo-and-).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you require your matrix first, instead of core's file. So that your matrix doesn't monkey patch, but define `Matrix` class. It's a good rule to require something explicitly before monkey-patching it.

Try to add `require 'matrix'` to your `core_ext/matrix`.

And you also can use `require 'core_ext/matrix'` without `_relative`. Just fix search path ($:) to contain your lib dir, if not yet.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question :-) In my Ruby example above, I am requiring my matrix before the Ruby's core but it works still. Why would it not work in rails?

Comment: I suggest you to try `pry` gem. Add `binding.pry` to the begin of test case, and check `show-method Matrix` in the debugger and inspect ancestors of the class.

Comment: I did debug with pry and `require 'matrix'` was giving me false as if the core matrix library was loaded but it was not. This is why I had my answer above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26715448/226255